# Execução esquisita de "Drag and Drop"

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer vários `div` terem a função "Drag and Drop".
Esse código funciona de forma que é possível adicionar e remover `divs` dinamicamente (não foi integrado no código ainda). O código funciona muito bem, mas quando é executado novamente (na adição ou remoção de novos `div`) ele passa a se comportar de forma estranha.

- Eles se mechem ao clicar em qualquer lugar do `div`, não apenas no titulo `h1` como antes.
- Não é mais possível escrever ou interagir com os `textareas`.
- Todos os eventos de movimentação vão para o ultimo `div` da lista.

(Clique em "Enviar" para executar a função de "Drag and Drop" novamente)

```js
var applyDrag = () => {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".contentCon")).forEach(e=>{
        
        e.querySelector("h1").onmousedown = null;
        dragElement(e);
        console.log(e.querySelector("h1").innerText);
    });
}

applyDrag();

var moveRoom = document.querySelector(".mainCon");

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    elmnt.style.background = "grey";  
    elmnt.style.border = "solid black 1px"; 
    var dragEl = elmnt.querySelector("h1");
    dragEl.style.cursor = "move";
    console.log(dragEl.innerText);
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    if (moveRoom) {
        moveRoom.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        dragEl.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        console.log(dragEl);
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="mainCon">
        <div class="contentCon" id="mainCode" style="position: absolute;"> 
            <h1>Bloco principal</h1>
            <button onclick="applyDrag()">Enviar</button>
            <br>
            <textarea cols="10" rows="10" spellcheck="false">Clique em "Enviar" para executar a função de "Drag and Drop" novamente.</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="contentCon" style="position: absolute;"> 
            <h1>Bloco final</h1>
            <br>
            <textarea id="ExitLog" cols="10" rows="10" spellcheck="false" readonly style="cursor: auto; width: 300;">Meu texto.</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi um erro bem simples. O código funciona na primeira vez pois `moveRoom` se inicia como indefinido. Na segunda execução `moveRoom` não é mais indefinido então o codigo não se aplica.

Simplesmente troquei:

```js
if (moveRoom) {
    moveRoom.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}
else {
    dragEl.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}
```

Por:

```js
dragEl.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
```